# sagepay TLS 1.2 update

Tags: opayo

Sagepay and all other doing transition from **TLS 1.1** to **1.2** as a security update.

Sagepay has three integration methods.

1. Sage Pay Form
2. Sage Pay Server
3. Sage Pay Direct

As per sagepay email, web servers integrating "Sage Pay Server" or "Sage Pay Direct" need to confirm their web server supports TLS 1.2

For "**Sage Pay Form**", web servers **not required** to support TLS 1.2 as credit information captured on sagepay itself?

Sagepay should mention it somewhere.

Comment: To SagePay People >> Please create your own forum / help site. Depending upon Stackoverflow is not a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

**SagePay Support Response:**

If you use “Sage Pay Server” or “Sage Pay Direct” Integration to process ecommerce payments you will need to ensure your systems use TLS 1.2 before the deadline dates below.

**Sage form does not require any updates**.

When your server connects to a Sage Pay server to process a transaction, Transport Layer Security (TLS) protocol encrypts the communications to keep them safe from malicious activity.

You or your developer can find out which TLS protocol your website uses by
entering your domain on a website like www.ssllabs.com

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SagePay for checkout from your web site and your site is coded with ASP.NET then just add the following code prior to making the call to Sage

```
            // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
            // Set protocol to TLS1.2
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            // Send the request
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(PayAction);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your application is returning the error [The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel], then you are possibly having the same issue as me.

This fix worked for me on Windows Server 2016, .net framework 4.5.2

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server

DWORD: Enabled

Value: 1

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server

DWORD: DisabledByDefault

VALUE: 0

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client

DWORD: Enabled

Value: 1

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client

DWORD: DisabledByDefault

VALUE: 0

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Server

DWORD: Enabled

Value: 0

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Server

DWORD: DisabledByDefault

VALUE: 1

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Client

DWORD: Enabled

Value: 0

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Client

DWORD: DisabledByDefault

VALUE: 1

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Server

DWORD: Enabled

Value: 0

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Server

DWORD: DisabledByDefault

VALUE: 1

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Client

DWORD: Enabled

Value: 0

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Client

DWORD: DisabledByDefault

VALUE: 1

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft.NetFramework\v4.0.30319

DWORD: SchUseStrongCrypto

VALUE: 1

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NetFramework\v4.0.30319

DWORD: SchUseStrongCrypto

VALUE: 1

Server restart is required.